# Is there any way to fetch the data type along with it's data sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I want to fetch the data type of attribute along with it's data using axios(sequelize)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 0):

You define the data type in your model, so you either somehow take it from there or you can hardcode it (which is not recommended) or write a function that returns data type based on the variable. Put it beside the data and return it in your API or whatever you have.